# Click on a polygon and then zoom and center map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon

I have a map with many polygons that are loaded from a kml file. I would like when clicking on a polygon to zoom in and center the map on this polygon.

Can you please guide me? I can't find a relative example in google maps api documentaton.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't fully possible, as the KmlLayer does not return the actual geometry of the feature that is clicked, so you won't be able to get the bounding box in order to get the best zoom of the polygon. At best, you can get the lat/lng on the polygon where the mouse click occurred, which you can get with the KmlMouseEvent

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#KmlMouseEvent

Here's some very simple sample code

```
kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(kmlMouseEvent) {
  var ll = kmlMouseEvent.latLng;
  map.panTo(ll);
  map.setZoom(19);
});
```

Comment: The pan option has an awkward result in my page. The map is flickering and can't understand if zooming or not.

Answer (score 0):

What works so far in my page is:

```
kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(event) {
            toggleKml(map); //change kml file
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                map.setZoom(10); 
                var text = event.featureData.name;

                var latitude = event.latLng.lat();
                var longitude = event.latLng.lng();
                console.log( latitude + ', ' + longitude );

                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                map.setCenter(point);

            }, 2000);   
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a good starting point: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml

In order to zoom after click this code did the job:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function (event) {
    map.setZoom(8);
});
```

Comment: The code posted will **not** center the map on a specific Polygon as you asked. It will zoom the map. That's all. So you are not even answering your own question...